# Configuring geckodriver in linux to use with Selenium

Tags: python, linux, selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to use geckodriver with selenium (python). However, everytime I try to run my script I get this message:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
I am working with Mint 20.3 Cinnamon and using Pycharm.
I tried several ways to include the driver in PATH. These are the two main:

1. In the terminal: "sudo apt-get install firefox-geckodriver"
2. The manual way at the terminal:
3. Downloaded the lateste version from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases. The file was geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
4. Extracted it with `tar -xvzf geckodriver*`
5. Made it executable `chmod +x geckodriver`
6. Moved it to my binary folder `sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/`
7. Included it to PATH export `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodrive`
   After performing this I tried to execute the script and still get the error.
   I also rebooted the programs and the system. Nothing seems to work so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use Geckodriver with Selenium Python quite often, and this Dockerfile can help you configure things on Linux: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/Dockerfile (or at least you can copy the exact steps from there as needed). It uses a Selenium Python framework called SeleniumBase.

The Dockerfile is optional for using SeleniumBase, but if you're not sure of the Docker setup steps, there's a ReadMe for it here: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/integrations/docker/ReadMe.md and a video of running Selenium tests on Linux here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-sno20R9P0 (although a few things in there might be slightly outdated). See https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase for the main SeleniumBase page.

You might also find the following GitHub Actions useful, which runs Selenium Python tests in Linux with different browsers: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/actions

- It is configured with the following `.yml` file: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/.github/workflows/python-package.yml